# Fedora 30 -- cannot reboot after (forced) power down

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

I powered down my machine by holding the button for 10 seconds. It no longer boots into Fedora 30.

What happens on reboot:
1. Enter PW to unlock LUKS after POST sucessful
2. System proceeds to print out green OK's.
3. System reaches "Started GNOME" (in green) and then the screen goes dark, keyboard no longer responds to any input.

I've not found much help online. Some google searches turned up editing the boot entry in the distro-selection screen, erasing "rhgb" or changing "quiet to "noquiet". Neither achieved the desired behavior.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling grub? See https://jfearn.fedorapeople.org/fdocs/en-US/Documentation/0.1/html/Fedora_Multiboot_Guide/GRUB-reinstalling.html

Comment: May help, may not, but check the kernel too (once you get things up and running again): I upgraded from Fedora 29 and then hit similar problems because the dnf upgrade option fails to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: That did not help....

Comment: I swear its something to do with the graphics. It POSTs, it unlocks LUKS, gets all the way to "started GNOME Display Manager" and freezes with a dark screen.